# Different PyCharm and IDLE Python versions

Tags: python, pycharm, versions

I have installed Python 2.7.9 64 and 32 bit versions. I have also installed PyCharm for better easing with the learning (I just recently started learning Python).
The problem is that Pycharm and IDLE show different Python versions when usng *sys.version*, even though they use the same path for the .exe.
How can I solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the path in PyCharm (in Options). PyCharm shows the first one it sees, and the IDLE shows the one you are using currently.